# How do I get two integer values from an input, Console.ReadLine(), in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, console

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var information= Console.ReadLine();
            var one= Int32.Parse(informatie.Split(' ')[0]);
            var two = Int32.Parse(informatie.Split(' ')[1]);
        }
    }
```

I want the user to type in two numbers, seperated by a whitespace, for example: 5 2. I want to capture the first number (5) in var one and the second number (2) in var two. The problem, however, is that my code doesn't work if the user, for example, types in two-digit numbers such as: 25 10. How can I make it work that my two variables one and two capture the numbers regardless of length? So another example, if a user types in: 348 3910 I want var one = 348 and var two = 3910. Another one: 2 4 , var one = 2 and var two = 4.

Comment: But it's working. How did you test it???

Comment: Your code should work. Can you show the inputs that cause your code to fail, and the wrong output that your code produces?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first split the string and then select the value from the array you want to use. You do not need to perform the split operation each time; you only need to do it once.  See the below code sample. You can also see it in this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XSD2f5).

```cs
var textSample = "320 520";

var textSplit = textSample.Split(' ');

Console.WriteLine(Int32.Parse(textSplit[0]));
Console.WriteLine(Int32.Parse(textSplit[1]));
```

Your code would look like this

```
var information= Console.ReadLine();
var textSplit = informatie.Split(' ')
var one= Int32.Parse(textSplit[0]);
var two = Int32.Parse(textSplit[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var information = Console.ReadLine();
        var one = Int32.Parse(information.Split(' ')[0]);
        var two = Int32.Parse(information.Split(' ')[1]);

        Console.WriteLine($" one is {one}");
        Console.WriteLine($" two is {two}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

and it works

This is the console:    [(Click here to see image...)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xubx.png)